# A method to UINavigationController as "viewDidLoad" to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, uikit, viewdidload

This may be a very stupid question. I'm just wondering

**Is there a method that would be called after a NavigationController has been segued?**

[which works just like `viewDidLoad` in `UIViewController`, besides `viewDidLoad` is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory]

If there isn't such a thing, is it possible to write one into the UIKit Framework??

(I know we can always use RootViewController's `viewDidLoad` to trigger something after a NavigationController has been segued. I'm just being curious..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are no views loaded by a `UINavigationController`. It just controls `UIViewControllers` that in turn control views. Therefore there is no need to have a callback like `viewDidLoad`.

Second, you already have a place where you can customize the `UINavigationController` after it has been created: in `prepareForSegue:` of the calling view controller, or in your app delegate if it is the root navigation controller.

Of course, you can always subclass `UINavigationController` and override its `init` methods if you want to encapsulate your modifications.

Comment: `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Therefore `UINavigationController` also has a `viewDidLoad` method and it works just like a "normal" view controller. A `UINavigationController` has a view that is loaded just like all other view controllers.

Comment: It is true that `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and that it inherits its methods. However, to assign a view to a navigation controller and populate it is a very unusual and actually nonsensical usage pattern. You could consider the navigation controller's `viewDidLoad` as one of the init methods I referred to.